# Change SP 2013 from Enterprise to standard edition

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, licensing

By Mistake I have added Enterprise Licence key istead of standard key during Sharepoint 2013 Installation. Now, I want to use Standard Licence key instead of Enterprise. Is there short way to do that.

Or should I unistall and install SP 2013 with standard Licence key?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to Enterprise, you can't go back to Standard. You would need to uninstall SharePoint and reinstall as Standard. Which, btw, won't be really simple since now Enterprise features are baked in to all your content databases. Your easiest option is to keep Enterprise and turn off Enterprise features for site collections.

Comment: I am ohk if my data is lost while un installation but my question is ,can I resuse that sharepoint server enterprise key for other setup? If I am using my SP Standard key for reinstallation ?

Comment: Yes, since every installation is linked to license key. How many servers do you have?

Comment: Only one..but will it count my current installation, If I will not use it any more?v It's standalone

Comment: if you uninstall and reinstall with the Standard license, you can use the Enterprise license for another installation, yes.

Comment: Ohk Mike Thankyou so much...

Comment: please share, if you have any microsoft link reference which explain this